# How to change default font size in report

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

How can I change the default font size in JasperReports's report?

I tried `net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.size` but it didn't work.

What I really want is to keep the same font and size when I export my report to pdf format using my application.

Pure *JasperReports* or even *Java* solutions are welcome.

Comment: Maybe it is a typo, try with `net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size` instead.

Comment: no change !!!!!

Comment: Just in case, this doc could help : http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be solved at least with help of two approaches:

- using styles
- setting [*net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size) property

### Using default style

We can create the default style in report and in case we did not specified attributes like font size for report's elements (for example, *textField* or *staticText*) the font size from default style will be applied.

#### Example

The *jrxml* will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Default font size" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="583" leftMargin="2" rightMargin="10" topMargin="2" bottomMargin="2" >
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="defaultStyle" isDefault="true" fontSize="20"/>
    <title>
        <band height="383">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="30" width="100" height="50"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="100" width="802" height="55"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In this report we have declaration of default style with font size: `<style name="defaultStyle" isDefault="true" fontSize="20"/>`

#### The output result

For template with default style the result generated in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be:

[image: The preview in JSS. Using default style]

Without using the default style the result will be:

[image: The preview in JSS. Without default style]

### Using *net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size* property

If we have a *Java* code for generating reports we can use our own copy of *jasperreports.properties* file.

I changed the default value with my own in *jasperreports.properties* file:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size=20
```

and rebuild report with *Java* code which use *JRPdfExporter* exporter.

For the same template, but without any style the result will be:

[image: The view of generated pdf file]

If we tried to change value of *net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size* property for example with *10* (this is a default value) the result will be:

[image: The view of generated pdf file]

---

*Notes:*

The *jasperreports.properties* file should be placed at classpath.